# Saving ENUM in spring data elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to save my entity in elasticsearch using spring data elasticsearch, all the attributes are saved (including objects) except for enum its always stored as null, this is my entity

```
@Entity
@Document(indexName="invoices", type="invoices", shards = 1)
public class Invoice {

@Transient
@JsonIgnore
@org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
private String searchIndex;

@Field(type = FieldType.String)
private InvoiceStateEnum state;
```

with and without @Field attribute state is being saved as null even though the object is being saved has value for this enum.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm using enums exactly the same way (with `@Field(type = FieldType.String)` for ES v2.x or `@Field(type = FieldType.text)` for ES v5.x) and they are saved into elasticsearch without any problems. Have you tried to debug the code and put a break point where you call invoceRepository.save(invoiceDocument) and check if `state` is properly set? Maybe something bad happens before saving?

Comment: you are using spring data elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes, I'm using spring data elasticsearch.

Comment: what is the version you are using?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce proper behaviour on two environments: ES v2.4.1 => spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch/1.4.5.RELEASE and ES v5.4.1 => spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch/2.0.0.M2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by removing folder data under my project and rerun the application, seems like for some reason elastic search was not updating the records so I was getting null since the attribute was added recently.

Answer (score 0):

As spring-data-elasticsearch uses Jackson, you can put the `@JsonFormat.Shape.STRING` annotation to your enum:

```
@JsonFormat.Shape.STRING
public enum InvoiceStateEnum {
  // your enum code
}
```

Comment: did not work, it is still saved in my elastic search as null, did you try it urself?